# How to select item in jComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have a jComboBox that I am populating with some objects. The objects are of a type which I have made myself, and include a String and an int. The object's toString method returns the String, which is displayed in the Combo Box.

Now, I wish to select an item in the Combo Box with code. How do I do this?

There are multiple items starting with the same letter

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I guess it is as simple as looking in the javadocs & tutorials: [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

```
JComboBox j = something;
...
j.setSelectedIndex(anIndex);
// or
j.setSelectedItem(anObject);
```

***EDIT:*** the setSelectedItem uses internally equals on the objects of the Model. So if the equals method of the Objects that you have in your model works on the "int" property of your object class then it will work as you expect even if two objects have the same "String" property.

Comment: Hi There, the thing is though, is that anObject has 2 fields, one is an int, and the other is a String. But maybe just setting it to the string will work... 

I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if you have your jcombobox in design mode.

In source mode, to get the selected item, the only thing that you need is converting the item selected in String.

Like this:

```
String cap=jgrado.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

After that you can save the Item for example:

```
pps2.setString(8,cap);
```

or in a jtextpane:

```
jtextpane.setText(jgrado.getSelectedItem().toString());
```